# How to insert values into a new added column of an already created table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, insert

I have first created a table and inserted values into it. Then I added a new column into the same table. But how do I insert values into this new added column of the same table.

I tried to insert values into this new column of the previously created table.

INSERT INTO db_name.table_name(Column_name)
VALUES
("x"),
("y"),
("z");

But it gives error and no values were inserted.

Comment: UPDATE rather than insert

Comment: To edit already inserted rows use UPDATE. If you don't provide at least a screenshot of how table looks and what error it gives you we will hardly be able to help.

Comment: If you could explain how?

Answer (score 0):

You can't give list of values you want to insert.

Either you need to use `where` clause if you want to set different values for specific rows. Something like below:

`UPDATE db_name.table_name SET column_name = 'X' WHERE row_id IN (1, 3, 5);`

If you want to insert same value you should give just one value not list of values. Something like below:

`UPDATE db_name.table_name SET column_name = 'X';`